# Controlling MacBook Pro with external MacBook Touch Bar

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar, sidecar

I've heard that in SideCar, you can control a MacBook Pro with the (simulated) Touch Bar on the iPad even if there is no physical Touch Bar on the MacBook. I don't own an iPad so I can't try this, but I do have an old 2017 MacBook Pro.

Is this possible with a MacBook Pro (2017) that has a physical Touch Bar? i.e. Is it possible to use the MacBook Pro (2017) Touch Bar to control the new m1 16-inch MacBook Pro?